# How do I disable Javascript in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

How do I disable Javascript in Chrome?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Click on the address bar —yea the ["omnibox"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95440?hl=en), if you prefer a cooler name— and type `chrome://settings/content`.

(Alternatively, go `Settings` and type “javascript” into the search box.)

You can disable JavaScript by selecting “Do not allow any site to run JavaScript”:

[image]

**It autosaves**; you don't have to click <kbd>Done</kbd> or anything else.

Indeed, we don't even need a mouse to disable JavaScript and get back to the current page:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
2. `chrome:settings` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. `javascript` <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> x 6, <kbd>▼</kbd>
5. Lastly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to close `Settings`.

should take about 5 seconds.

Comment: Just a note: the Wrench menu is not a wrench anymore. Don't know how to describe it though...

Comment: @MegaHit, Yea that "cool name" isn't actually much of a hype that Google wishes it to be. Post edited.

Comment: Does it need page refresh?

Answer (score 12):

Another way:

**Quick Javascript Switcher**, a Chrome extension for quickly enabling / disabling Javascript) :

- Chrome webstore: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje
- Github: https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that QJS breaks certain CSS3 styles and properties, such as transitions.

Answer (score 8):

Open Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I or F12) -> Preferences (F1) -> Section Debugger -> Disable JavaScript
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

via http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5e291648113cc731&hl=en:

> To disable JS on Windows, find your Google Chrome
>   shortcut (say, on your desktop or
>   somewhere similar). Right-click it, and go to
>   Properties. In the "Target:" field,
>   put "-disable-javascript" after the
>   quotation marks.

Any better ways?

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way by now.

Answer (score 3):

There are two built-in methods to disable Javascript in Chrome:

1. in Chrome settings
2. in Chrome developer tools

### Chrome settings method

1. open Chrome settings
2. click content settings button under Privacy (see picture)
3. select the option to disable javascript

[image]

### Chrome developer tools method

1. open dev tools (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> in OS X)
2. click the gear icon (red box below)
3. click the disable javascript option (second down as of writing)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this that might be easier:

Pull up the Chrome Console, and click on the settings icon in the lower-right. At the top in "General" is the option to disable Javascript - along with lots of other easier-to-access goodies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using [NotScripts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notscripts/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn), because it blocks more than just JavaScript, allows for both temporary and permanent exceptions, and it actually has a decent UI (unlike Chrome's built-in functionality).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje) extension.

Comment: This is exactly the same suggestion as @mlb